# How to save changes to Ember.js model without breaking its relationships

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am using the latest version of Ember-data (v1.0.0-beta.2)
I have a problem updating an Ember.JS model. I reduced this case to most simplistic model

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  subject: DS.attr('string'),
  author: DS.belongsTo('user')
});

App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  msg: DS.attr('string')
});
```

I save it using .save() method, and it successfully resolves the promise. I've added some logging to show the problem

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions: {
    save: function() {
      console.log("Author name before: " + this.get("model").get("author").get("name"));
      this.get("model").save().then(function(m) {
        console.log("Author object after: " + m.get("author"));
        console.log("Author name after: " + m.get("author").get("name"));
      });
    }
  }
});
```

After saving, the author property becomes just a number 1, not an object.

The JSON returned by the server is always the same. To be able to demonstrate this on JSbin, I had to overwrite DS.RESTAdapter.ajax.

http://jsbin.com/EWUSEkA/3/edit?html,js,output

The question is: How to make Ember sideload or by other means resolve object relationships after saving the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue with beta 2.  The bug report has some suggested workarounds.

https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/1228

Hopefully it'll be fixed in beta 3.